# How to update the size of the layout with Jung when using the picking mode?

Tags: java, graph, visualization, jung

I wondering how to change the size of the layout associated to a VisualizationViewer with jung?

I explain the purpose: actually, when using a SatelliteVisualizationViewer, we can pick a node and move it in an area that is not covered by the SatelliteVisualisationViewer.

We can see this in the SatelliteViewDemo class in the JUNG distribution. Launch the demo, pick a node and move it outside the layout size. The node is well displayed in the VisualizationViewer but not in the satellite view.

So, I try to add some code in the MouseListener of PickingGraphMousePlugin, specifically in the mouseReleased(...) method in order to update the layout size by the size of the rectangle that contains all the nodes of the graph. Doing this, the SatelliteView should be updated.
But how to do this?

**Edit:** Sorry to have not detailled enough. In fact, changing the layout size does not change the SatelliteView, so vertex located outside the layout (after a pick and move operation) are still not covered by the SatelliteView.

Maybe I have miss something...

Actually the real question is: how to change the area covered by the SatelliteVisualizationViewer? !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to automatically update the satellite view relatively to a VisualizationViewer with picking support enabled.

I have finally adopted another solution: no automatic update of the satellite view but a pan using mouse button 2, and a zoom using CTRL+Mouse_Wheel.

Here is the class, it may be helpful... :

```
public class SatelliteVisualizationViewerMouseControler implements
        MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener {

    private SatelliteVisualizationViewer<SVertex, PEdge> vv;
    private Point drag_point;
    private double zoom_factor = 0.1;

    public SatelliteVisualizationViewerMouseControler(
            SatelliteVisualizationViewer<SVertex, PEdge> vv) {
        this.vv = vv;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (drag_point != null) {
            Point2D l_drag_point = vv.getRenderContext()
                .getMultiLayerTransformer()
                .inverseTransform(Layer.LAYOUT, drag_point);

        Point2D l_e_point = vv.getRenderContext()
                .getMultiLayerTransformer()
                .inverseTransform(Layer.LAYOUT, e.getPoint());

        double delta_x = l_e_point.getX() - l_drag_point.getX();
        double delta_y = l_e_point.getY() - l_drag_point.getY();

        double scale = vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer()
                .getTransformer(Layer.VIEW).getScale();

        vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer()
                .getTransformer(Layer.LAYOUT)
                .translate(delta_x * (1 / scale), delta_y * (1 / scale));

        drag_point = e.getPoint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) {
            drag_point = e.getPoint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) {
            drag_point = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        if (e.getModifiersEx() == MouseEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK) {
            vv.getRenderContext()
                    .getMultiLayerTransformer()
                    .getTransformer(Layer.LAYOUT)
                    .scale(1 + (e.getWheelRotation() * zoom_factor),
                            1 + (e.getWheelRotation() * zoom_factor),
                            vv.getCenter());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got a pretty good idea of how to proceed.  What piece are you stuck on?  Changing the layout size?  Updating the visualization?  Something else?

Comment: Sorry to have not detailled enough.

In fact, changing the layout size does not change the SatelliteView, so vertex located outside the layout (after a pick and move operation) are still not covered by the SatelliteView.
Maybe I have miss something...

Actually the real question is: how to change the area covered by the SatelliteVisualizationViewer? !!!

Comment: You will need to change the VV dimensions (using setSize()) as well as the layout dimensions.  (It may help to think of the layout and visualization coordinate spaces as different, because they are.)  Once you've done that, you'll need to refresh the visualization.

Comment: I have investigated into that, but this not make the solution closer.
Actually you can still put a vertex outside the area covered by the satellitevisualizationviewer. Think about a vertex can be picked and moved to "the nord" and extending the layout or the satellitevisualizationviewer size will not make the vertex displayed.

Another thing: refreshing the SatelliteVisualizationViewer is not sufficient, we have to fireStateChange().